# RegExp date validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I just learned regular expressions and I created a dd-mm-yyyy date validator with regular expressions:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(19|20)\d\d$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[**Debuggex Demo**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/MkF8nDmgg73UKu6E)

It seems to work fine. But i was wondering if there are any improvements that could be made to make sure there will be no errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: This kind of validation is impossible (or, at least, not practical) with regular expressions. Dates are not strings.

Comment: what about 1/1/2000 seems like a valid data to me, not everyone add leading 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel. Take help of built-in date parsing method [**`Date.parse(String)`**](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2) like this:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse(str); // str is your input string for data
var date = null
if (isNaN(timestamp) == false)
    date = new Date(timestamp);
else
    alert("Invalid date");
```

Comment: Date.parse wraps invalid dates, so `2013-02-29` will be validated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to include [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) into your project? Then you can just write:

```
moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false
```

You can also use your own format string if you want to. ;-) This would also give you the advantage that it veryfies if the date actually exists (think of 29-02-2013, which is not existant).